# Not displaying the extracted data

Tags: python

I have a question. Currently, I am working on project to extract data from pdf invoice. I am facing a problem regarding data extraction. Following code is for extracting the data.

```
import PyPDF2
pdfreader= PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("G:\\RPA_testing\\PO_450012345.pdf")
page = pdfreader.getPage(0)
content = page.extractText()
print(content)
```

output:

```
LZE Packaging
Ludwig strasse 23, 44560, Germany
Internet : www.lze.com Email: info@lze.com
PHONE    : +8801723123456
Date
12.08.2021
DEF INDUSTRY LIMITED
fedrichschafen strasse 102, 66890, Germany
PO
L-123456
Order Responsibility : Martin 
Email: martin@lze.com
SL. No
QTY
Unit 
Price
01.
2560
1.95
```

Next step, I have to extract specific information. I have written a code for that. But that doesn't work. Can anyone help to find a solution?

```
i=0
for row in content.split('\n'):
    line=content.split('\n')
    if "LZE Packaging" in content:
       company = "LZE Packaging"
       print(company)    
       if row.startswith('PO'):
           order_number = line[i+0]
           print(order_number)
       if row.startswith('Date'):
           Order_Date = line[i+0]
           print(Order_Date)        
       if row.startswith('QTY'):
           quantity = line[i+3]
           print(quantity) 
       if row.startswith('Unit'):
           unit_price = line[i+3]
           print(unit_price)
```

I am not getting any output. I know i am making something wrong. But I cannot find out. What is the problem with my coding?
Anyway, I need below result.

order number:L-123456
order date: 12.08.2021
Qty: 2560
unit price: 1.95

Regards,
Ekram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indexing logic is off, and you never increment `i`. Also, it's unclear what the first `if` condition is for. Try this instead:

```py
rows = content.split('\n')
company = rows[0]
print(company) 

for i, row in enumerate(rows):  
    if row.startswith('PO'):
        order_number = rows[i+1]
        print('order number:', order_number)
    if row.startswith('Date'):
        Order_Date = rows[i+1]
        print('order date:', Order_Date)        
    if row.startswith('QTY'):
        quantity = rows[i+4]
        print('quantity:', quantity) 
    if row.startswith('Price'):
        unit_price = rows[i+3]
        print('unit price:', unit_price)
```

```
LZE Packaging
order date: 12.08.2021
order number: L-123456
quantity: 2560
unit price: 1.95
```